# remote(from another computer) turtlebot joystick teleoperation doesn't work

Tags: ros, joystick, teleop, remote, joy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi. I have a problem with joystick teleoperation from another computer. I am running turtlebot_gazebo simulator. Tested on home wireless network. Joystick teleoperation works ok, but not from remote computer. Remote keyboard teleoperation works fine.

**rostopic echo /joy** prints joystick data, but there is no data at **/cmd_vel**

Whats the problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29828/remote(from-another-computer)-turtlebot-joystick-teleoperation-doesn%27t-work/) by [drinovc](https://answers.ros.org/users/1985/drinovc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-03-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is probably a network configuration issue. Take a look [Network Setup](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/NetworkSetup) wiki page.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2012-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1